# Using IIS to terminate and re establish SSL

Tags: ssl, iis

I have a query in relation to handling SSL Certs. Essentially there is a requirement to decrypt the SSL Cert, inject into the Header and re-encrypt prior to sending on.

How do I achieve this using IIS to terminate and re-establish the connection but ensuring that my CA signed cert is used.

Comment: I haven't done this. But these blogs seems like they might point you in the right direction: https://rdingwall.com/2013/09/24/howto-set-up-an-ssl-offload-termination-proxy-with-iis-7/ , https://blog.lint.at/iis-as-reverseproxy-with-ssl-offloading/

Comment: You are looking for "ssl-intercept" "ssl-offloading"